# How to convert DATE_TRUNC to MariaDB?

Tags: sql, postgresql, mariadb

I have the following select statement in PostgreSQL:

```
DATE_TRUNC('{{time_interval}}',u.created_at) AS "Signup Date",
```

Where {{time_internal}} is a variable set to `month`

I need to convert that line to MariaDB, here's what I have so far:

```
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), u.created_at) AS "Signup Date",
```

This is not outputting the results as expect leaving me to believe I migrated this line of SQL incorrectly.

What did I do wrong when migrating the line of SQL from PostgreSQL to MariaDB?

Comment: Is this right? `DATE_FORMAT(u. created_at, '%Y-%m-01') AS "Signup Date",`

Comment: What was wrong with the method I gave you in the last question? i.e. `DATE_FORMAT(u.created_at, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')`? You can probably skip the `00:00:00` part if you don't actually require time

Comment: https://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=399

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a `case` statement:

```
select (case when @timeinterval = 'day'
             then date(u.created_at)
             when @timeinterval = 'month'
             then u.created_at + interval (1 - day(u.created_at)) day
             when @timeinterval = 'year'
             then makedate(year(u.created_at), 1)
        end) as Signup_Date
```

There are other possibilities, but `'day'`, `'month'`, and `'year'` are the most common date parts.